# Real Analysis, Cauchy but not null.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I came across this question in a book on p-adic numbers and thought it looked interesting. However, I am having trouble getting started with it. Any hints/suggestions is much welcomed

Let $(a_n)$ be Cauchy but not null. Show there exists a $c>0$ and $N>0$ such that $||a_n||>c$ when $n>N$.

Comment: What is a null sequence?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think that means a sequence which converges to 0.

Comment: @LorenoHeer presumably, he's working with [$p$-adic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom oh, I did not read proper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to be more specific about where we are working. I'll assume that we are in an arbitrary normed linear space $(X,||.||)$. Suppose the contrary, namely: $(\forall \ \epsilon > 0)$ $(\forall \ N > 0)$ $(\exists \ k > N)$ $(||a_k|| < \epsilon)$. Then, $0$ is an accumulation point of $(a_n)$, and we know that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy. This is a contradiction (why?).

Comment: It's already clear from the question that he is refering to the p-adic numbers, but since the p-adic numbers (at any stage in their construction) are a normed linear space, your argument still holds.